# Ruby show specific list of user names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have list that shows all users names:

```
<p>all special users: <%= @users.count('special', :distinct => true) %></p>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
            <p><%= user.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

table schema:

```
t.string   "name"
t.boolean  "special", :default => false
```

but what if i want to show only 'special' user names that has boolean enabled(true) how do i do that?
- Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a filter:

```
def User
  scope :special, -> { where(special: true) }
end

# view
@users.special.count
@users.special.each do |user| ...
```

[**Read the documentation**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: i've got a jar of dirt thx http://media.tumblr.com/24412dd41e70512c439b4b7561bc44ed/tumblr_inline_n0gdg77OyK1rflnou.gif

Comment: @JohnnyDerp you're insane.